# Loading Wordnet into Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, wordnet

I am trying to explore wordnet and would like to import it into neo4j, because:

1. I find the graph database easy to use and a good way to analyze relationships
2. While I understand the concept of triples and rdf/owl, I do not at all find them easy to work with yet

My problem though is that I am a javascript developer and have seen no advice for how to do this with node.js. I have found a few resources with java, but my experience with java is extremely rusty and sorely lacking, so the few guides and papers I have found just go way over my head in terms of implementation. I did find this [piece of code](https://gist.github.com/joshsh/5047451) though, that was designed to load from the files [here](https://github.com/jrvosse/wordnet-3.0-rdf). I loaded up eclipse and imported the correct dependencies (i think) from maven and tried running it, but keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError which I cannot root cause.

Has anyone tried to use this code as well and had success recently, or can someone recommend another approach for me to load Wordnet into neo4j?

```
 11:08:52.835 [main] WARN  o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openrdf/model/impl/SimpleValueFactory
    at org.openrdf.rio.RDFFormat.<clinit>(RDFFormat.java:97)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSail.<init>(GraphSail.java:109)
    at WordnetLoader.load(WordnetLoader.java:42)
    at WordnetLoader.main(WordnetLoader.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openrdf.model.impl.SimpleValueFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

EDIT: Jan recommended that I add the sesame runtime dependency (see comments). New errors are showing (errors removed at next edit)

EDIT: I was receiving additional errors, Jan recommended trying lucene 3.6 rather than the newer version I was running. Upon updating my dependencies, it seems like the application was able to run, though it did so with errors saying that it was unable to access the data in the rdf files correctly.

```
loading file: C:\Users\Dhirj\Documents\Neo4j\wordnet\basic-partial.ttl.gz
org.openrdf.rio.RDFHandlerException: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: No active transaction
    finished in 10ms
loading file: C:\Users\Dhirj\Documents\Neo4j\wordnet\Manifest.ttl
    at org.example.WordnetLoader$SailConnectionAdder.handleNamespace(WordnetLoader.java:116)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parsePrefixID(TurtleParser.java:361)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseDirective(TurtleParser.java:272)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseStatement(TurtleParser.java:250)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:214)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:158)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.load(WordnetLoader.java:70)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.main(WordnetLoader.java:32)
Caused by: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: No active transaction
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.verifyIsActive(SailConnectionBase.java:162)
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.setNamespace(SailConnectionBase.java:709)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader$SailConnectionAdder.handleNamespace(WordnetLoader.java:114)
    ... 7 more
org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: Expected ':', found 'h' [line 1]
    at org.openrdf.rio.helpers.RDFParserHelper.reportFatalError(RDFParserHelper.java:440)
    at org.openrdf.rio.helpers.RDFParserBase.reportFatalError(RDFParserBase.java:685)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.reportFatalError(TurtleParser.java:1405)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.verifyCharacterOrFail(TurtleParser.java:1227)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parsePrefixID(TurtleParser.java:347)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseDirective(TurtleParser.java:272)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseStatement(TurtleParser.java:250)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:214)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:158)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.load(WordnetLoader.java:70)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.main(WordnetLoader.java:32)
    finished in 2ms
loading file: C:\Users\Dhirj\Documents\Neo4j\wordnet\neo
loading file: C:\Users\Dhirj\Documents\Neo4j\wordnet\void.ttl
org.openrdf.rio.RDFHandlerException: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: No active transaction
    at org.example.WordnetLoader$SailConnectionAdder.handleNamespace(WordnetLoader.java:116)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parsePrefixID(TurtleParser.java:361)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseDirective(TurtleParser.java:272)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseStatement(TurtleParser.java:250)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:214)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:158)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.load(WordnetLoader.java:70)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.main(WordnetLoader.java:32)
Caused by: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: No active transaction
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.verifyIsActive(SailConnectionBase.java:162)
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.setNamespace(SailConnectionBase.java:709)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader$SailConnectionAdder.handleNamespace(WordnetLoader.java:114)
    ... 7 more
    finished in 1ms
loading file: C:\Users\Dhirj\Documents\Neo4j\wordnet\wn31.nt.gz
loading file: C:\Users\Dhirj\Documents\Neo4j\wordnet\wnbasic-schema.ttl.gz
org.openrdf.rio.RDFHandlerException: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: No active transaction
    at org.example.WordnetLoader$SailConnectionAdder.handleNamespace(WordnetLoader.java:116)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parsePrefixID(TurtleParser.java:361)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseDirective(TurtleParser.java:272)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parseStatement(TurtleParser.java:250)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:214)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:158)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.load(WordnetLoader.java:70)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader.main(WordnetLoader.java:32)
Caused by: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: No active transaction
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.verifyIsActive(SailConnectionBase.java:162)
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.setNamespace(SailConnectionBase.java:709)
    at org.example.WordnetLoader$SailConnectionAdder.handleNamespace(WordnetLoader.java:114)
    ... 7 more
    finished in 1ms
```

My current maven build is as shown below:

```
  C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-runtime\2.8.6\sesame-runtime-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-model\2.8.6\sesame-model-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-api\2.8.6\sesame-repository-api-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-query\2.8.6\sesame-query-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-manager\2.8.6\sesame-repository-manager-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-event\2.8.6\sesame-repository-event-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-http\2.8.6\sesame-repository-http-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-sparql\2.8.6\sesame-repository-sparql-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-contextaware\2.8.6\sesame-repository-contextaware-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-sail\2.8.6\sesame-repository-sail-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryalgebra-model\2.8.6\sesame-queryalgebra-model-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-http-client\2.8.6\sesame-http-client-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.4\httpclient-4.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4\httpcore-4.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-api\2.8.6\sesame-sail-api-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-federation\2.8.6\sesame-sail-federation-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.10\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryparser-api\2.8.6\sesame-queryparser-api-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryparser-serql\2.8.6\sesame-queryparser-serql-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryparser-sparql\2.8.6\sesame-queryparser-sparql-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-api\2.8.6\sesame-queryresultio-api-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-binary\2.8.6\sesame-queryresultio-binary-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-sparqljson\2.8.6\sesame-queryresultio-sparqljson-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.4\jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-sparqlxml\2.8.6\sesame-queryresultio-sparqlxml-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryresultio-text\2.8.6\sesame-queryresultio-text-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\3.2\opencsv-3.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-repository-dataset\2.8.6\sesame-repository-dataset-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-http-protocol\2.8.6\sesame-http-protocol-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-api\2.8.6\sesame-rio-api-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-datatypes\2.8.6\sesame-rio-datatypes-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-languages\2.8.6\sesame-rio-languages-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-binary\2.8.6\sesame-rio-binary-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-jsonld\2.8.6\sesame-rio-jsonld-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\github\jsonld-java\jsonld-java\0.5.1\jsonld-java-0.5.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient-cache\4.2.5\httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.7\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-ntriples\2.8.6\sesame-rio-ntriples-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-nquads\2.8.6\sesame-rio-nquads-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-n3\2.8.6\sesame-rio-n3-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-rdfjson\2.8.6\sesame-rio-rdfjson-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-rdfxml\2.8.6\sesame-rio-rdfxml-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-trix\2.8.6\sesame-rio-trix-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-turtle\2.8.6\sesame-rio-turtle-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-trig\2.8.6\sesame-rio-trig-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-inferencer\2.8.6\sesame-sail-inferencer-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-model\2.8.6\sesame-sail-model-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-lucene\2.8.6\sesame-sail-lucene-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-lucene-api\2.8.6\sesame-sail-lucene-api-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\spatial4j\spatial4j\0.4.1\spatial4j-0.4.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers-common\5.1.0\lucene-analyzers-common-5.1.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-memory\2.8.6\sesame-sail-memory-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-base\2.8.6\sesame-sail-base-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-nativerdf\2.8.6\sesame-sail-nativerdf-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-sail-rdbms\2.8.6\sesame-sail-rdbms-2.8.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.0.13\logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.0.13\logback-core-1.0.13.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\tinkerpop\blueprints\blueprints-neo4j-graph\2.6.0\blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.6.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\tinkerpop\blueprints\blueprints-core\2.6.0\blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.3.3\jettison-1.3.3.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.2.3\jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.2.3\jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\carrotsearch\hppc\0.6.0\hppc-0.6.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-kernel\1.9.6\neo4j-kernel-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-lucene-index\1.9.6\neo4j-lucene-index-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-graph-algo\1.9.6\neo4j-graph-algo-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-udc\1.9.6\neo4j-udc-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-graph-matching\1.9.6\neo4j-graph-matching-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-cypher\1.9.6\neo4j-cypher-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.0\scala-library-2.10.0.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\concurrentlinkedhashmap\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru\1.3.1\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-jmx\1.9.6\neo4j-jmx-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-ha\1.9.6\neo4j-ha-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-backup\1.9.6\neo4j-backup-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-consistency-check\1.9.6\neo4j-consistency-check-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-com\1.9.6\neo4j-com-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.6.3.Final\netty-3.6.3.Final.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-cluster\1.9.6\neo4j-cluster-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.3.2\zookeeper-3.3.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-management\1.9.6\neo4j-management-1.9.6.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\allenai\tinkerpop\blueprints\blueprints-graph-sail\2.7.1\blueprints-graph-sail-2.7.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\allenai\tinkerpop\blueprints\blueprints-core\2.7.1\blueprints-core-2.7.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\net\fortytwo\sesametools\common\1.8\common-1.8.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-queryalgebra-evaluation\2.7.10\sesame-queryalgebra-evaluation-2.7.10.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-util\2.7.10\sesame-util-2.7.10.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\3.6.2\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-queries\3.6.2\lucene-queries-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\jakarta-regexp\jakarta-regexp\1.4\jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-highlighter\3.6.2\lucene-highlighter-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-join\3.6.2\lucene-join-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-grouping\3.6.2\lucene-grouping-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-memory\3.6.2\lucene-memory-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers\3.6.2\lucene-analyzers-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-queryparser\3.6.2\lucene-queryparser-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial\3.6.2\lucene-spatial-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-misc\3.6.2\lucene-misc-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spellchecker\3.6.2\lucene-spellchecker-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-icu\3.6.2\lucene-icu-3.6.2.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\4.8.1.1\icu4j-4.8.1.1.jar
C:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-stempel\3.6.2\lucene-stempel-3.6.2.jar
```

Comment: Please add the complete error stack trace to your posting. And at which level do you get this error? Within eclipse or when you try to start the packaged application?

Comment: added stack trace. Assuming it is not the java 7 vs 8, as the libraries that is showing the error is distinct from the neo4j library mentioned. Additionally, java 8 docs indicate that it is only in rare edge cases that the backwards compaitibility will be an issue - granted its still possible it could cause issues here... but I guess I'm just hoping its not..

Comment: I get the error when I hit run. it shows in the eclipse console, but after it's done compiling and the application is actually running.

Comment: So this error is caused by rdf4j. You need to include this to your dependencies as well probably

Comment: `<groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>`                                     `<artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>`                                    `<version>2.8.6</version>`

Comment: I think you lost the links in your question. I've put WN in N4J several times with different tools, but 1) I'm not sure from your question what exactly your problem is (WN is not an RDF store, yet your question seems to be about some RDF API in Java) and 2) there are more than one ways to model WN in N4J, so it's also not clear to me what your end goal is. I'm interested in what you're doing and I'll try to help if you repair the links and help me understand your purpose better.

Comment: Links restored thanks :)

Comment: My end goal is really to just play with word net, see how the connections work, and then play around with it to see if I can leverage it any apps I'm working on or have worked on in the past. I really only found out about it last week, and I think it sounds like a pretty awesome tool! So to answer your question, my question is:  How can I get a copy of WordNet in neo4j? neo4j because it is the graph db I am familiar with, and enjoy using. I do not ultimately care too much about how I get it into neo4j, just that I end up with a copy in neo4j that I can play with.

Comment: I have had success with Aliaksandr Autayet's [extJWNL](http://extjwnl.sourceforge.net/). I used it to iterate over all synsets, and over each synset's semantic and lexical pointers, generating Cypher queries from these and sending them to the transactional REST endpoint of a Neo4j server. It may be more involved than using Sesame and Blueprints, but it worked well for me.

Comment: Ok cool. I'll try playing with that. Do you happen to have a class implementing a solution already lying around that I could refer to?

Answer (score 1):

### Initial Answer

So nobody has yet posted an answer, but we could just try to replicate it. When I try to use the `SimpleValueFactory` from `org.openrdf.sesame` without linking the dependency in the maven pom.xml, I get the same error so maybe that will help you out:

Adding this to your maven dependencies:

```
<groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
<artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>
<version>2.8.6</version>
```

I am not sure about the correct version though but they showed how to include the sesame framework here: http://rdf4j.org/sesame/tutorials/getting-started.docbook?view

### Update after Dude included the sesame-runtime

It is probably not a problem with Java 8. See this question with multiple answers telling that, neo4j has no problems with Java 8: [Neo4j 2 and Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434010/neo4j-2-and-java-8)

Do you use **Lucence 4** for your project? Try using **Lucence 3.x**.

There seems to be a custom fix as well on github which one could probably integrate in a project. See here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6

Comment: Thanks! I added your recommended dependency, but am getting more errors. I edited the question to show the new trace. Can you tell me which version of Java you are running btw? Looking at the new stack track I am thinking that the issue that remains may now lie there.

Comment: Attempted reverting back to java 7 (just in case) and got errors still. Reverted to lucene 3.6 and app ran with errors. Updated question to reflect new errors.